# symphony xsl include

Tags: xslt, include, symphony-cms

in my index.xsl I have this:

```
<xsl:include href="../utilities/onenicebox.xsl" />
```

but I would like this to appear only when I visit first time index.xsl, so not after navigating around the website and returning to home page.

I tried `include_once` and `import` but both return errors and break the page.
any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would need to set a cookie and check for its existence/value before displaying the box on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

There's an old extension that do this trick http://getsymphony.com/download/extensions/view/20781/, but it is incompatible with S2.3.2. With a little bit effort I think it can be updated for your need.